# Javascript to reset a Django form field in a specific section of the form?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm trying to use a tiny piece of javascript:

```
$("#btn_clear").click(function(){
    $("#two")[0].reset();
        });
```

to reset a section of a form which i have inside a div. the form has multiple sections (divs), but i only want it to clear the form fields inside a specific div

html pseudocode:

```
<form ...
    <div id="one" ...
        <div id="two" ...
            <label for=...                                                                
                {{ form.startdate }}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                {{ form.startdate.errors }}
                ...
```

I'm trying to use this button (also in the html) combined with the javascript to clear div id="two":

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_clear" style="margin-left: 142px" value="Reset" type="button">Clear Section</button>
```

When i click the button nothing happens and I don't get any errors in the console. Is there something special I need to do to clear a django form field in this manner?

Comment: can you share the full HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<div id="two" ...

<script>
$("#btn_clear").click(function(){
    $("#two :input").val('');
 });   
</script>
```

**EDIT**

For checkboxes:

```
$("#btn_clear").click(function(){
    $("#mydiv :input").val('');
    $("#mydiv :input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', false);
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gd6mbcvz/27/

Comment: this might work, but there are some checkbox form fields in the div section so i don't think this will reset the checkboxes. i'll try to post what i can of the html

Comment: The previous Dev was doing some weird bootstrap stuff but this put me on the right track!